# Spring mvc controller combine 2 models

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a model:

```
User.java
Role.java
```

I created a model to combine the 2 models:

UserRole.java

```
class UserRole{
    private User user;
    private Role role;

    getter and setter
}
```

and in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUser(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userrole", new UserRole());

        return "create";
    }
```

for my jsp I added a form to input details

Create.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/home/create/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="userrole"
    <td><springForm:input path="user.name" /></td>
    <td><springForm:input path="role.type" /></td>
<input type="submit">
<form:form>
```

When I go to url /create

I get an error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

I'm guessing in the controller:

```
public String listUser(Model model) {
```

Should I create a service or dao for this UserRole model or is the error something else?

Comment: Looks like you need `<springForm:input path="userrole.user.name" />` and the same for `userrole.role.type` because you place in the model "userrole" attribute.

Comment: add log in the controller and check your controller whether invoked or not. maybe create.jsp render directly.